# Cordova + Angularjs - Why does $resource (or $http) called from inside a callback give a 404?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I dumped a perfectly functional angularjs web app into cordova and compiled for ios. In testing for ios, if I try to access a local file from inside a callback response (from also accessing a local file for which I get a perfectly respectable 200) I get a 404. I changed it so both the initial request and the request from the callback are the same file. Still same error. If I change it to a remote url, it works fine. Code below:

```
function promiseFunc1() {
  var wait = $q.defer();
  $http.get('config/resources.json').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    wait.resolve(data);
  });
  return wait.promise; 
}

function promiseFunc2() {
  var wait = $q.defer();
  $http.get('config/resources.json').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    wait.resolve(data);
  });
  return wait.promise; 
}

promiseFunc1()
 .then(function (result) {
   return promiseFunc2()
 })
 .done()
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If your `config` folder is outside `www` then use

```
$http.get('../config/resources.json')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Mathews. It was inside www. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is security in navigator (CORS) to access a file.

so you need to use API phonegap in the link :

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Hi, @Ilyas. Thanks. I guess I'm going to have to use the API. I was having the same issue with html partials, and I realized that others were embedding all their partials in their index.html instead of saving them separately. I guess this is why?

Comment: the use of partials allows a modular and clearer code. I advice you to work with partial as its not blocking you